# passing require method's argument using variable in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, require

whenever i store the corresponding file path into a variable

```
let source = './products/image/sunglass.jpg'
```

and pass it as require method's argument

```
require(source)
```

it gives

> module not found error

but if I write the require method following way, it then works perfectly.

```
require('' + source)
```

why this is happening......

Answer (score 0):

it is because in the first case you are passing the whole image not its  path but if you contact it with `''` then it is converted to a string that is why it is working fine

Comment: how?
the source variablel hold a string of path, not the image